# adMob iOS resume (back to app button)

Tags: ios, timer, admob, resume

I have a little game with a timer.
I'm implementing adMob to monetize and I am not able to restart timer/ads after user clicks on the banner and come back to the app.

The flow is:

- 1 - game start
- 2 - show ads
- 3 - click on banner and pause timer
- 4 - oper safari
- 5 - click "back to my app" link/button (iOS feature)
- 6 - back to the app and restar timer (**problem here**)

I had implemented all adMob events method (and insert restar timer code) but I can't get out of this issue.
The code work because it worked with iAds (I'm migrating to adMob).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

EDIT:
here is the code:

```
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewDidReceiveAd");
  self.pauseTimer = NO;
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)adView
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  self.pauseTimer = NO;
}

/// Tells the delegate that a full screen view will be presented in response
/// to the user clicking on an ad.
- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillPresentScreen");
  self.pauseTimer = NO;
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full screen view will be dismissed.
- (void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillDismissScreen");
  self.pauseTimer = NO;
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full screen view has been dismissed.
- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewDidDismissScreen");
  self.pauseTimer = NO;
}

/// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
/// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
- (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillLeaveApplication");
  self.pauseTimer = YES;
}
```

Comment: post code for AdMob events methods so we can see what's going on. looks like the event is going back to the app so you're wanting the app delegate methods and not the AdMob events methods

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs many many thanks for your reply/support. I spended all night on it. I edited and added the code...

Comment: I just gave an answer. Give it a try and see if it works for you. If not I can provide another answer.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs OMG! <3.<3 Thank you. I'll give it a try and I'll come back.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs but is there something corrisponding to -(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner and    -(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave? Because in iAds I used this method to pause and restart timer. :(

Comment: [Look here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ad-events#registering_for_banner_events) Doesn't look like AdMob has those methods.

Comment: I started from Ad Events Guide. But I can't understand which methos is call when I use back-to-app button or when the view appear...
I tried by placing the self.pauseTimer in viewDidLoad and/or viewWillAppear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this VC create a property to store this

`@property (nonatomic) BOOL didGoToSafari;`

```
- (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)adView {
  NSLog(@"adViewWillLeaveApplication");
  self.pauseTimer = YES;
  self.didGoToSafari = YES;
}
```

In the VC that you show right before the ad would show in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` you should put this code

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:)
   name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
   object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

And then after `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`, write this function

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

if (self.didGoToSafari = YES){

      self.pauseTimer = NO;
      self.didGoToSafari = NO;
}
    }
```

In `viewWillDisappear`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self                                  name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Basically what you're doing is listening to see if the app became active again. If it did, check to see if it's coming back from Safari. It's not perfect because you could feasibly be using the app, user goes to Safari and then doesn't go back to or close the game. They could then use Safari later and then go back to the game and it would start running again. There probably some control flow in the `AppDelegate` you could use to code around this, but in general this code should do it.

EDIT: As per your comment about understanding it, here's the full explanation.

You are using [`NSNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/) to listen for when the app returns to an active state. `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is automatically called when your app becomes active (it's an app delegate method). When it does, the method `(void)applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` gets called automatically and the methods in that method get called. You have a boolean flag to see if the app is returning from Safari because your app could return from any other app if user switched to another app when the ad got pushed. In the end, you remove your VC as an observer to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: It worked like a charm! You're great! Thank you so much... u rock! :))
I'll read and read again you're explanation to understand to way it works. I hope it will not be hard to fix "bug" flow u've mentioned.

Comment: @frankypa I saved you some time and updated the answer so you don't have to read and read it again.

Comment: thank you very much! You were clear but I'm a noob and junior as iOS dev and I need/like to understand the theory. Thumb up for you and big thank again! :))